# PyQT threading error while passing a signal to a QMessageBox

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qmessagebox

I tried to receive a string from a thread to my main GUI using SIGNALs. Everything works fine until I want to use the string in a QMessageBox. Printing out is no problem but starting a QMessageBox gives me several errors (some are about QPixmap which I even do not use in the GUI.

Here is a short working example of my code:

```
import sys
import urllib2
import time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class DownloadThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)


    def run(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("threadDone(QString)"), 'test')


class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.list_widget = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Start")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.start_download)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.list_widget)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.downloader = DownloadThread()
        self.connect(self.downloader, QtCore.SIGNAL("threadDone(QString)"), self.threadDone, QtCore.Qt.DirectConnection)

    def start_download(self):
        self.downloader.start()

    def threadDone(self, info_message):
        print info_message
        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self,
                    u"Information",
                    info_message
                    )
        #self.show_info_message(info_message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm getting this erros:

> QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different
> thread
>
> QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread

This error only while moving the mouse and QMessageBox is still open:

> QObject::startTimer: timers cannot be started from another thread
>
> QApplication: Object event filter cannot be in a different thread.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is the first time I'm using threads.

Thank you!
Stefanie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`QtCore.Qt.DirectConnection` -- this option means that the slot will be called from the signal's thread. Your code has (at least) two threads running: the main GUI thread and the `DownloadThread`. So, with this option, the program tries to invoke `threadDone` from `DownloadThread`, and tries to create a GUI object outside the GUI thread.

This leads to: `QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread`

Remove this option and the default behavior (wait to return to main thread before invoking the slot) should clear up the error.